# Custom Docker Bridge w/ Fedora 22

Tags: docker, network-interface

I've been following the manual [here](http://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge), but I'm having trouble getting docker to use the new bridge.

I've added the following to `/etc/default/docker` and `/etc/sysconfig/docker` but as soon as I start the docker service it continues to use the `docker0` bridge.

The established `docker0` IP range blocks many internal IPs on my network. I simply want to configure it to use a 192.168.5.0/24 range.

```
$ netstat -r
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 bridge0
```

Comment: Can't you just use the default bridge but use the `--fixed-cidr=` daemon argument to control the range?

Comment: @AdrianMouat I feel like it's a hack. It would prove complex to replace the docker.service contents with the additional flag. I should be able to set the flag inside an external configuration.

Comment: I don't follow that reasoning. It's not a hack, it's the supported way of doing things. That file *is* the external configuration! Besides, you will have to edit the file to set the `-b` argument anyway.

Comment: @AdrianMouat I never said it wasn't supported, but I'm anticipating this configuration to work `echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-b=bridge0"' >> /etc/default/docker` but it does not. It's far easier to assume I can use Chef  or puppet to configure the host by establishing the above configuration.

Comment: I still don't follow. The file you need to edit depends on your distribution, it's not a docker thing. If you run `ps` you'll be able to see the arguments the daemon was started with. Why is `DOCKER_OPTS="-b=bridge0"` easier than `'DOCKER_OPTS="--fixed-cidr=192.168.5.0/24`?

Comment: I assumed that the external configuration would work. The manual suggested 2 configuration files, but neither were successful. Editing the docker.service file, by the way does work, but I'm not a fan of deploying an entire .service file when it forks from convention. For example, setenv.sh in tomcat is the only files I should be editing to set OPTS. Not the tomcat.service file.

Comment: Yeah, this a Red Hat configuration issue, not a Docker one. The example you were following was for Ubuntu, it would be nice if they also had a Red Hat example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I'm doing wrong.
The vendor suggests creating a conf file under `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` to override directives and preserving the `docker.service`

```
# cd /etc/systemd/system/
# mkdir docker.service.d
# cd docker.service.d
# vi override.conf
```

Then add the following directives (the ExecStart twice to reset the first in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`):

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
```

Then daemon-reload and start docker

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start docker
```

[systemd Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/)

Comment: Hmmm... updated docker-engine today and it blow away my `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file. That's not nice.